# Does the timing of a game release affect sales?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I know that in [Game Dev Story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-dev-story/info), the time you release your game can have a noticeable affect on sales (ex. early December). The in game hints and tutorials don't mention timing releases at all.

Does releasing games at a certain time increase or decrease sales?

Comment: Don't know the answer to what the question is directly asking (month of release) but once you're visiting G3 each year, this event adds a significant amount of hype to whatever game you're working on at the moment which can have a dramatic improvement on sales, especially with the large booths if you get lots of visitors

Comment: I noticed that, and it works the same way if you host your own convention. Also, if you go to G3 and you aren't working on a game, the next project you start will already have some hype at the beginning.

Comment: Indeed - and as you get more fans you will generate hype just by developing a game, with the hype slowly developing over the course of development. In all instances, not releasing a game quickly after development has completed will result in hype decreasing over time but it's still worth ensuring you fix all your bugs before hitting Finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, A little bit, if you get a booth in G3 while making a game, your hype and more fans can't wait to buy the game, so it is a slight increase, but timing does help, but marketing works more. As you get more fans you will generate hype just by developing a game, with the hype slowly developing over the course of development.

Comment: I don't think you get free hype if you're not making a sequel and haven't marketed the game at all, though I might be wrong.

Comment: I played the game through. Yes, You do, in the third office.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of hype gained from the G3 event depends on the number of people visiting your booth.  And the number of people who visit your booth depends on the size of the booth and how many fans you have.

(If I could find a way to post a comment without making an account I would have done that instead.)